# 'If' identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, undeclared-identifier

I am a beginner C++ learner and I always have a problem on if loop in visual studio 2010

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    string name;
    int money;

    cout << "Hello, Enter your name here: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "\n\nHello " << name << ".\n\n";

    cout << "\nEnter your salary here:L";
    cin >> money;

    If(money <= 50000 || money >= 100000 );
    {
        cout << "\nGood!\n";
        } else if(money >=49999){
               cout << "\nJust begin to work?\n"
               } else if(money <= 100000){
                      cout << "\nWow!, you're rich\n";
                      }else{
                            cout << "\nMillionaire\n";
                            }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler said 'If' identifier can not be found.
Help needed please.
Thanks

Baramee

Comment: `If` is capitalised?  It should be all lower case `if`

Comment: Also there is a semicolon after the conditional statement which won't do what you want it to do and in fact you'll get an unmatched else

Comment: In addition are your comparisons the right way round?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if` doesn't designate a loop, but a conditional. Note that it's lower-case `if`, as opposed to what you have - `If`.

Also, you need to remove the trailing semicolon.

This line:

```
if(money <= 50000 || money >= 100000 );
```

does nothing.

The following:

```
if(money <= 50000 || money >= 100000 ) //no semicolon here
{
    cout << "\nGood!\n";
} 
else if(money >=49999)
{
}
```

executes the first block if the condition is true.

Answer (score 6):

C++, like many programming languages, is case-sensitive.  Make sure you type it as `if`, not `If`.